# why is Rubocop raising “parser/current recognizes 2.5.5-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.5.3”?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

In a Rails app I have started seeing the following in logs and test outputs.

```
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby25, which recognizes
warning: 2.5.5-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.5.3.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
```

This is coming from Rubocop.

I had understood that Rubocop checks whether a .ruby-version file exists in the app root and uses the Ruby version it specifies. https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#setting-the-target-ruby-version

The Rails app contains such a file

```
/.ruby-version
ruby-2.5.3
```

Why is Rubocop running checks against the wrong version of Ruby?

Answer (score 4):

It's coming from [parser](https://rubygems.org/gems/parser), a dependency of [rubocop](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubocop#:%7E:text=parser).

https://github.com/whitequark/parser/blob/master/lib/parser/current.rb

Looking at this code it seems that if you are not using the last minor version of Ruby you're getting this warning.